# Is there any way to use jpa library like those used spring-boot in a javaFX project?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, jdbc, javafx

I've been working through an online spring-boot course directed by [in28minutes](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-master-class), the way it configures a connection to a database through JPA library is very neat. However I'm now working on a JavaFX project, it requires me to use JDK7_025 and JavaFX SDK 2.1.(which is quite old). I wonder if we can combine the newest JPA method to do the connection work instead of old fashioned JDBC way to save us more time without writing those plumbing codes? Any approach will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Your data access code is completely independent from your UI code. There is nothing to stop you using any ORM in your JavaFX project.

Comment: I wonder if you have actually looked at any docs for those technologies, or if you have actually tried anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. E.g. [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) or  is a good choice for using JPA standalone in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hibernate. It is very easy to integrate and lightweight too. You can use [this guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/) to kick start